# Publishing a game on Google Play with a fake name

Tags: publishing, google-play

I'm almost publishing my game to Google Play, but I wonder if I can use an fake name, I mean, not using a fake name with a real names, just some words like **Lazer Dude** or anything else, because I don't want to show who am I, I wanna keep my anonymously. There's no problem to use an fake name?

Comment: Have you read the license agreement of google play? I'm pretty sure you must provide real information. If you want to not have your own name there, maybe you could get away with it if you created a game company or something.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt, if I had a game company I certainly would show my name, but I'm just a ordinary guy that made a simple game. I have read the license of google play, but it doesn't answer my doubts. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: As Josh Petrie's answer says they allow you to pick a name to show as the author of the app. That will be the name the people downloading the app will see in the app description in Google Play. You cannot lie to Google itself when you create the developer account, and doing so is probably a terrible idea. So far, I don't see how somebody may get to your real name by your chosen display name. They also let you use a different e-mail to show in the app description than the one associated to your developer account, so you can protect your e-mail too (the one shown to people must exists).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot hide your real name from *Google*. The [distribution agreement](https://play.google.com/intl/ALL_us/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html) you enter into is between you (or your company) and them, and they will require sufficient personal information from you in order to allow you to distribute (and in return, disburse your payments) that they'll be able to identify you.

The public-facing name you use doesn't have to be your own (as near as I've been able to tell), as long as you don't pick something that would be [impersonating](https://play.google.com/about/ip-deception-spam/impersonation-ip/impersonation/) some other intellectual property or brand.

You can consider [filing a DBA (doing-business-as) registration](https://www.sba.gov/starting-business/choose-register-your-business/register-your-business-name) (or the equivalent outside the US). This is a fictitious name legally associated with your business entity (which would be a sole proprietorship in this case). It may provide some additional legitimacy.

You should consult a lawyer familiar with business law and practices to be 100% sure, as I am not.

Comment: You will almost always be traceable back to a human _somehow_, though.

Comment: Couldn't you just make an LLC?  There are anonymous ways to do this last I checked.

Answer (score -5):

Call them on a land line or cell phone and ask.